# how can I send ISO-8859-1 XML file using SoapClient?

Tags: php, xml, soap-client, iso-8859-1

I'm consuming a SOAP method which expects a XML content with ISO-8859-1 encoding. I tried add it directly as a method parameter but SoapClient returns an encoding error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string '<?xml version="1.0"
>   encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>(...)' is not a valid utf-8 string

If I convert the XML content to UTF-8 the SOAP server doesn't recognize the XML content.

Any solution using SoapClient?
Any alternative using cURL?

Comment: According to the official docs you can't as the encoding is always utf-8 `The encoding option defines internal character encoding. This option does not change the encoding of SOAP requests (it is always utf-8), but converts strings into it.`: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like pointed by Constantin GALBENU, it cannot be done using SoapClient.
I had to use cURL instead, sending charset at content-type header:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1",
    "Accept: text/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```